# How can I calculate log returns for a financial year different from calendar year in R?

Tags: r

I want to calculate log returns for a stock in R. The issue is that my financial year is from April 1 to March 31. I have tried using packages tidyquant and tidyverse. The code I have tried is as follows:

```
library(tidyquant)
RIL<- tq_get("RELIANCE.NS") # download the stock price data of Reliance Industries Limited listed on NSE of India. The data is from January 2011 to May 2021.
library(tidyverse)
RIL1<- RIL %>% mutate(CalYear = year(date),
                      Month = month(date),
                      FinYear = if_else(Month<4,CalYear,CalYear+1)) # This creates a new variable called FinYear, which correctly shows the financial year. If the month is >3 (ie March), the financial year is calendar year +1.
RIL_Returns<- RIL1 %>% 
     group_by(FinYear) %>% 
     tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
                  mutate_fun = periodReturn,
                  period = "yearly",
                  type = "log") #This part of the code has the problem.
```

From this code, I get two values for log returns per each year. This can't be true. I want a table with columns FinYear and Log_Returns, where Log_Returns is defined as ln(adjusted close price for the last trading day of given FinYear/adjusted close price for the first trading day of the given FinYear). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is not the most elegant but I think it works, I obtained the first and last day of each year manually and computed the log returns accordingly

```r
# Get data
library("tibble")
library("tidyquant")
RIL<- tq_get("RELIANCE.NS")
RIL1<- RIL %>% mutate(CalYear = year(date),
                    Month = month(date),
                    FinYear = if_else(Month<4,CalYear,CalYear+1))

# Get minimum and max dates in each year
start_dates = c()
end_dates  = c()
for(year in format(min(RIL1$date),"%Y"):format(max(RIL1$date),"%Y")){
        start_dates = 
            c(start_dates,
            min(RIL1$date[format(RIL1$date, "%Y") ==  format(as.Date(ISOdate(year, 1, 1)),"%Y")])
            )
        end_dates = 
            c(end_dates,
            max(RIL1$date[format(RIL1$date, "%Y") ==  format(as.Date(ISOdate(year, 1, 1)),"%Y")])
            )
}

# Get filtered data
RIL2 <- RIL1[(RIL1$date %in% start_dates | RIL1$date %in% end_dates),]

# Get log returns, even indexes represent end of each year rows
end_adjusted = RIL2$adjusted[1:length(RIL2$adjusted) %% 2 == 0]
beginning_adjusted = RIL2$adjusted[1:length(RIL2$adjusted) %% 2 != 0]
log_returns = log(end_adjusted/beginning_adjusted)

# Put log returns and years in a tibble.
result = tibble(log_returns ,format(RIL2$date[1:length(RIL2$date) %% 2 == 0], "%Y"))

# Result
result
```

Outputs

```r
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   log_returns `format(RIL2$date[1:length(RIL2$date)%%2 == 0],…
         <dbl> <chr>                                           
 1     -0.412  2011                                            
 2      0.185  2012                                            
 3      0.0739 2013                                            
 4      0.0117 2014                                            
 5      0.145  2015                                            
 6      0.0743 2016                                            
 7      0.537  2017                                            
 8      0.215  2018                                            
 9      0.306  2019                                            
10      0.287  2020                                            
11      0.0973 2021
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. I created a custom function "log_return <- function(x){
     return(log(tail(x,1)/head(x,1)))#the last value divided by the first value, and taking the natural log of that answer". Then from this function, I used dplyr's group_by(FinYear) and summarize(LogReturns = log_return(adjusted) to calculate log returns.